# want to fetch database records in foreach loop, which is in laravel blade/view file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Codeigniter View File Code:

```
<?php
    $i = 1; 
    if($recentOrders) {
        foreach($recentOrders as $row) {
            $shpname = $this->admin->getDataFromTableWithWhere('ci_user',array('user_id'=>$row->user_id));
            $StatusName = $this -> admin -> getDataFromTableWithWhere('ci_order_status',array('status_id'=>$row->status_id));
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i?></td>
    <td><?php echo ucfirst($shpname[0]->shop_name); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->order_no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ucfirst($StatusName[0]->name); ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php }
    $i++;
} ?>
```

Now same i've to use it in laravel view(blade) file

want to fetch database records in foreach loop (which is in laravel view/blade file)

please give me idea??

Comment: Apart from the question, I think you need to utilize blade template. You missed `foreach` tag, `if` tag, and probably those `php` tags is uneeded.

Comment: no.. this is CI code snippet.. I've to convert it into laravel code.. how can i?

Comment: Do you have any existing Laravel model? I expect you have created it. Also I need the table structure so I can give you the right direction.

Comment: order table:
order_id,
user_id,
status_id,
....
....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, don't be lazy next time

```
@if($recentOrders)
    @php
    $i = 1;
    @endphp

    @foreach($recentOrders as $row)
        @php
        $shpname = DB::table('ci_user')->where('user_id', $row->user_id)->first();
        $StatusName = DB::table('ci_order_status')->where('status_id', $row->status_id)->first();
        @endphp

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $i }}</td>
            <td>{{ ucfirst($shpname->shop_name) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->order_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ ucfirst($StatusName->name) }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        @php
        $i++;
        @endphp
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: please upvote / accept it as right answer, so another people that have the same problem with you would notice this,